# hibernate 2nd level cache hits=0 for two successive identical queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

Got a problem setting up 2nd level cache for hibernate for my Spring+Hibernate project or I don't understand how it works.

I have one table roughly defined as this

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region="testCache")
public class TestClass extends MSId {
     @Transient
     STATUS statut = STATUS.NORMAL;
     public FamilleCatalogue(int id) {
          this.id = id;
     }
}
```

In my configuration I have this :

```
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="dbtest" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.generate_statistics" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
        <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName" value="/spring/persistence/single/hibernate/ehcache.xml"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_reference_entries" value="true"/>
```

my ehcache.xml contains :

```
<cache
    name="testCache"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="3600"
    timeToLiveSeconds="3600"
    statistics="true"
    logging="true"
    maxElementsInMemory="100">
</cache>
```

Now in my test I query all the element of my test class using this :

```
Query q = this.getEntityManager().createQuery("FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName());
List<E> result = q.getResultList();
return result;
```

The thing is that I query 2 times the whole lot of them expecting that the second time the resulting object Will be taken from the 2nd level cache instead of the direct query in the database. However, each time I launch the query, all my entities are retrieved from the database and put in the cache as shown in the traces below :

```
======> Query all test objects (1)
      --> Entity Load Count                : 297
      --> 2nd Level Hits                   : 1
      --> 2nd Level Misses                 : 1
      --> 2nd Level Puts                   : 296
======> Query all test objects (2)
      --> Entity Load Count                : 593
      --> 2nd Level Hits                   : 1
      --> 2nd Level Misses                 : 1
      --> 2nd Level Puts                   : 592
```

- Can anyone explain this ?
- Why does the number of puts gets incremented if the objects are already present in the cache ?
- Is it because 2nd level cache is only used when querying by ID ?
- Does this have to do with the QueryCache that I should enable ? because when I enable it, it's slower to retrieve datas from the query cache than to acctually query the database ...

Precision : the hit=1 is the result of a Query by Id I launched on a specific object.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You will need to enable the query cache and make the query cacheable. Without it the cache will not be used (unless queried by id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query-level cache**

This is an optional feature and requires two additional physical cache regions that hold the cached query results and the timestamps when a table was last updated. This is only useful for queries that are run frequently with the same parameters.

```
Query q = this.getEntityManager().createQuery("FROM " + entityClass.getSimpleName());
query.setCacheable(true);
List<E> result = q.getResultList();
return result;
```

More about query cache [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/pitfalls-hibernate-second-0)

Comment: thaks for the tip. I knew about that link (been on this problem quite a while) but it seems I didn't read carefully enough :). One other thing though I also noticed that I have a `maxElementsInMemory="100"` and my query contains `296` elements. Therefore I think it hits the DB each time to retrieve all the results from the Query. Augmented that and the time is now `4s` to retrieve more than `50K` object the first time and `0.71` s for subsequent calls. Now QueryCache is not a hasle anymore :). Thanks for your help.